# Is a past-tense *when* clause acceptable with a present perfect main clause?

Tags: tense, past-tense, perfect-constructions

> He has helped me when I **was** lonely.

Is this past tense ok?

Comment: That sounds fine to me -- I'm an AmE speaker. But if you are in school, I have no idea how a teacher might grade that. :)

Comment: @F.E. "He has helped" sounds incorrect to me, I think "He HAD helped" sounds better. What do you think?

Comment: @Anonymous That "had" version seems to have a slightly different type of meaning, for it has cut off the present time from the situation that was being described. (Assuming that we aren't taking about fiction prose.) The present-perfect version ("has") implies that the described situation has current relevance for the present -- while the past-perfect version ("had") doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

This is unremarkable in colloquial speech, but it is only marginally acceptable in  formal registers.

Strictly speaking, you should not qualify a present perfect, which is a statement about the present, with temporal adjuncts which do not include the present; and *when I was lonely* refers exclusively to past occasions. You would do better to cast the *when* clause, too, in the present perfect. or to cast both in the simple past

> He has helped me when I have been lonely.
>   He helped me when I was lonely.

The past-tense *when* clause is acceptable, however, if it is positioned as a ‘supplement’ or afterthought:

> He has helped me—when I was lonely, and when I needed a friend.